# string.Format with string.Join

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I've tried making a string like this:

```
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10]
```

With this code:

```
string nums = "[" + string.Join("][", Enumerable.Range(1, 10)) + "]";
```

That, however, doesn't really look very good, so I was wondering if I could combine *string.Format* with *string.Join*, sort of like this:

```
string num = string.Join("[{0}]", Enumerable.Range(1, 10));
```

So that it wraps something around each item. However, that ends up like this:

```
1[{0}]2[{0}]3[{0}]4[{0}]5[{0}]6[{0}]7[{0}]8[{0}]9[{0}]10
```

Is there a better/easier way to do this?

---

Among all the solutions, I must say I prefer this

```
string s = string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(i => string.Format("SomeTitle: >>> {0} <<<\n", i)));
```

Over this

```
string s2 = "SomeTitle: >>>" + string.Join("<<<\nSomeTitle: >>>", Enumerable.Range(1, 4)) + "<<<\n";
```

Because all the formatting is done in one string, not in multiple.

Comment: why is your former solution not good - it looks perfect to me! :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
string.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(i => string.Format("[{0}]", i)))
```

Comment: Just a side note: this works only in framework >= 4. For the older versions you need to turn Concat argument into an array, for example adding `.ToArray()`

Answer (score 16):

I wanted something like this, but with a possibility to enter a format string and a separator. So this is what I came up with:

```
public static string JoinFormat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, string separator,
                                   string formatString)
{
    formatString = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formatString) ? "{0}": formatString;
    return string.Join(separator,
                       list.Select(item => string.Format(formatString, item)));
}
```

Now you could make a list like

> [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]

by entering `numbers.JoinFormat(", ",  "[{0}]")`.

Whereas a `Concat` solution with `"[{0}],")` would have a trailing comma.

An empty or `null` separator produces your list.

Comment: I believe this should be an answer. It's universal.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a LINQ solution such as

```
string nums = String.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                                      .Select(i => string.Format("[{0}]", i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just concatenate each item, and use [`String.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat) to put them together:

```
string num =
  String.Concat(
    Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(n => "[" + n + "]")
  );
```

If you want to get fancy, you can make a cross join between the numbers and a string array. :)

```
string num =
  String.Concat(
    from n in Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    from s in new string[] { "[", null, "]" }
    select s ?? n.ToString()
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    str.AppendFormat("[{0}]", i);

Console.WriteLine(str.ToString());
```

My recommendation is to use StringBuilder to append the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Join(',', Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => string.Format("'{0}'", i)))
```

String Join can be better option than Concat